# How to define a map<> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know how use a map in Flutter. I tried the documentation also but it does not work. I want to define a map in Flutter, with a function which adds `<k,v>` to the map from other classes. Someone told me to declare a global map, but I don't think that's a good idea if you have something else, please help.

```dart
class Global extends StatelessWidget {
  var  myMap = {
    "one": "asd",
    "two": "asd2",
    "three": "aad3",
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: "I want to define map in flutter with a function which add to the map from other classes also", meaning??? please elaborate...

Comment: can you please elaborate on why you need to use the map?

Comment: see i have 6 classes containing each containing number of list tiles when the user tap on one listtile it will move to the next class  so i want to store the data that user tap on which tile and i can use this information in the end(end is book button ) so i m thinking to add those data in a map

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Map<String, String> someMap = {
    "one": "asd",
    "two": "asd2",
    "three": "aad3",
  };
```

Instead of this

```
 var  myMap = {
    "one": "asd",
    "two": "asd2",
    "three": "aad3",
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for adding value to Map

```
`void main() {
  var myMap = {
    "id": "jay",
    "password": "1234",
    "name": "Jay Tillu",
  };
  print("************ Before adding data in Map ************");
  print(myMap);

  // Adding value to Map

  myMap["country"] = "india";
  print("************ After adding data in Map ************");
  print(myMap);
}`
```

Comment: when you're adding country getting an error "expecting a class try to place this code in class"

Answer (score 1):

```
var details = {'Username':'tom','Password':'pass@123'}; 
print(details);
```

or

```
var details = new Map(); 
details['Username'] = 'admin'; 
details['Password'] = 'admin@123';
details.forEach((k,v) => print('${k}: ${v}')); //forEach enables iterating through the Map’s entries.
```